# I can't display the image on the discord channel using the bot

Tags: c#, discord.net, imagesharp

I want to output an image to the channel using the Imagesharp framework, or rather I'm new to This framework. Initially, I got this error "Can't convert from" SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image "to"string". I tried to solve the problem by writing string a = $ " {zx}"; await ReplyAsync(a) and it didn't work.

```
    int Width = 640;
    int Height = 480;

    [Command("cmd")]
    public async Task TestCmd()
    {
        

        var zx = Image.Load("Images/1ub.jpg");
        {
            
            zx.Mutate(x => x.Resize(zx.Width / 2, zx.Height / 2));

            zx.Save("Images/1ub.jpg");
          
        }

        string a = $"{zx}";
       

        await ReplyAsync(a);
    }
```

Comment: You can't post an image as a string. Use `SendFileAsync` to send the image.

Comment: @Anu6is he writes to me: I can't convert from "SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image" to " string"

Comment: you either send a filepath as a string or you send the file as stream

Comment: @Anu6is Yes, you are right I send as a string, tell me how to send as a file

Comment: if you are saving the file to disk then just send the save location.

Comment: @Anu6is Well, you helped me but not the way I wanted, it turned out so I added the path to the image in await and it went to my channel but if I add a variable to await the image will not come out :(

Comment: @Anu6is  But no you helped me I have polucilasi, thank you very much :)

Comment: I really think you need to take the time to learn C# before continuing so that you understand how string interpolation works. You're also leaking memory for every image.